# Compare many javascript values

Tags: javascript

I have this problem: I am getting values ​​from selects and saving in variables to do the comparison in the if and display text. This is for a quote using functions in javascript.

The problem is that I need a way to optimize this, since it is not very practical for me.

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="titular">
            Titular
        </div>              

<div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
  
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">elige edad</option>
    <option value="1">18-50 Años</option>
    <option value="2">51-65 Años</option>
  </select>
</form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant1">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="1mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="1mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="1mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
<!--------------- FILA 1 FINAL------------------>
<!-- FILA 2 DE INICIO-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 " id="">
            conyuge
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
    <form>
  
          <select id="">
            <option value="">elige edad</option>
            <option value="1">18-50 Años</option>
            <option value="2">51-65 Años</option>
          </select>
    </form>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="2ant2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="2ant3">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="2ant4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>

<!-- FILA 2 FINAL -->
<!--------------- FILA 3 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_1">
                <option value="0">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant3">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="3mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="3mod3">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="3mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
<!--------------- FILA 3 FINAL------------------>

<!--------------- FILA 4 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
           <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_2">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant4">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="4mod2">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="4mod3">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="4mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
<!--------------- FILA 4 FINAL------------------>

<!--------------- FILA 5 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_3">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant5">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="5mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="5mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="5mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>

    <!--------------- FILA 5 FINAL------------------>


    <!--------------- FILA 6 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 4
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_4">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant6">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="6mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="6mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="6mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>


<!--------------- FILA 7 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 5
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_5">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant7">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="7mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="7mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="7mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>



<!--------------- FILA 8 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 6
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_6">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant8">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="8mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="8mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="8mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>

<!--------------- FILA 9 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 7
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_7">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant9">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="9mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="9mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="9mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>

<!--------------- FILA 10 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 8
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_8">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant10">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="10mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="10mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="10mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
<!--------------- FILA 11 INICIO------------------>

<!--------------- FILA 12 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 9
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_9">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant12">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="12mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="12mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="12mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>


<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
            Hijo 10
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
             <form>
              <select id="val_hijo_10">
                <option value="">elige edad</option>
                <option value="1">0-24 Años</option>
              </select>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="cant12">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="12mod2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="12mod3">
           $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos" id="12mod4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
        
    </div>


    <!--------------- FILA 13 INICIO------------------>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos font-weight-bold" id="">
           Suma Asegurada Total
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="final_1">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="final_2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="final_3">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="final_4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
    </div>

     <!--------------- FILA 13 FINAL------------------>

     <!--------------- FILA 14 INICIO------------------>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos font-weight-bold" >
           Costo Quincenal
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="pago_1" id="pintar">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="pago_2">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="pago_3">
            $0.00
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 clear-pesos color-blue font-weight-bold" id="pago_4">
            $0.00
        </div>
        
    </div>

     <!--------------- FILA 14 FINAL------------------>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" id=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-azul btn btn-lg btn-block"><h4 class="font-weight-bold">Cotizar</h4></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="">   
          <button type="button" onclick="reseteo()" class="btn-rosa btn btn-lg btn-block"><h4 class="font-weight-bold">Limpiar</h4></button>
        </div>
        
        
        
    </div>





  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("val_hijo_1").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("val_hijo_2").value;
  var f = document.getElementById("val_hijo_3").value;
  var g = document.getElementById("val_hijo_4").value;
  var h = document.getElementById("val_hijo_5").value;
  var i = document.getElementById("val_hijo_6").value;
  var j = document.getElementById("val_hijo_7").value;
  var k = document.getElementById("val_hijo_8").value;
  var l = document.getElementById("val_hijo_9").value;
  var m = document.getElementById("val_hijo_10").value;

else if (
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && f== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && g== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && h== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && i== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && j== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && k== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && l== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && m== 1) ||

         (x== 2 && e == 1 && d== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && f== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && g== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && h== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && i== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && j== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && k== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && l== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && m== 1) ||
 )

{
//modulo1
document.getElementById("cant1").innerHTML = "$75,000.00";
document.getElementById("cant2").innerHTML = "$75,000.00";
document.getElementById("cant3").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";
document.getElementById("cant4").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";
}
```

if the condition is not met, go to the next

```
 if (x == 2 && d == 1 && e == 1 && f == 1){

//modulo1
document.getElementById("cant1").innerHTML = "$75,000.00";
document.getElementById("cant2").innerHTML = "$75,000.00";
document.getElementById("cant3").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";
document.getElementById("cant4").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";
document.getElementById("cant5").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";


//modulo 2
document.getElementById("1mod2").innerHTML = "$150,000.00";
document.getElementById("2ant2").innerHTML = "$150,000.00";
document.getElementById("3mod2").innerHTML = "$90,000,00";
document.getElementById("4mod2").innerHTML = "$90,000,00";
document.getElementById("5mod2").innerHTML = "$90,000,00";

//modulo3
document.getElementById("1mod3").innerHTML = "$225,000.00";
document.getElementById("2ant3").innerHTML = "$225,000.00";
document.getElementById("3mod3").innerHTML = "$135,000,00";
document.getElementById("4mod3").innerHTML = "$135,000,00";
document.getElementById("5mod3").innerHTML = "$135,000,00";


//modulo3
document.getElementById("1mod4").innerHTML = "$300,000.00";
document.getElementById("2ant4").innerHTML = "$300,000.00";
document.getElementById("3mod4").innerHTML = "$180,000,00";
document.getElementById("4mod4").innerHTML = "$180,000,00";
document.getElementById("5mod4").innerHTML = "$180,000,00";

//--------------------------------------cantidad total asegurada mayor--------------------------------------//

 // document.getElementById("cantfinal").style.font = "normal bold 20px arial,serif";
 //modulo1
  document.getElementById("final_1").innerHTML = "<h3>$285,000,00</h3>";
  //modulo2
  document.getElementById("final_2").innerHTML = "<h3>$570,000,00</h3>";
  //modulo3
  document.getElementById("final_3").innerHTML = "<h3>$855,000,00</h3>";
  //modulo4
  document.getElementById("final_4").innerHTML = "<h3>$1,140,000,00</h3>";


  //document.getElementById("costo").style.font = "normal bold 20px arial,serif";
  //modulo1
  document.getElementById("pago_1").innerHTML = "<h2>$65,00</h2>";
  //modulo2
  document.getElementById("pago_2").innerHTML = "<h2>$130,00</h2>";
  //modulo3
  document.getElementById("pago_3").innerHTML = "<h2>$195,00</h2>";
  //modulo4
  document.getElementById("pago_4").innerHTML = "<h2>$260,00</h2>"

}
```

Comment: Please post enough code for the context of your question to make sense (we have no idea what `x`, `d`, and `f` (and so on) represent. Post the related HTML and the complete `if` statement. Also remove extra whitespace.

Comment: And, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Get values ​​from select and save to variable x,d,e,f,g,h...

Comment: How many variables more you need to read the next part of the tutorial where they show arrays?

Comment: 10, update the code

Comment: Please, as I already indicated, post ALL the relevant code. You only have half of the `if` statement in your question and you need to include the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this ?

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
var d = document.getElementById("val_hijo_1").value;
var e = document.getElementById("val_hijo_2").value;
var f = document.getElementById("val_hijo_3").value;
var g = document.getElementById("val_hijo_4").value;
var h = document.getElementById("val_hijo_5").value;
var vars = [f,g,h];

if(x==2){
    if(d == 1 || e == 1){
        
        for(var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++){
            if(vars[i] == 1){
            //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```